# Absolute coequalizers in $\mathbf {Set} $

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $ A $ be a set and let $ R\subseteq A\times A $ be an equivalence relation on $ A $. Denote by $ p, q $ the projections $ R\longrightarrow A $ on the first and second factor, respectively. The coequalizer of $ p $ and $ q $ is then given by the projection $ A\longrightarrow A/R $ assigning to each element of $ A $ its equivalence class modulo $ R $.

Using the fact that epimorphisms in $\mathbf {Set} $ are split, or equivalently, the axiom of choice, it is shown in  *Handbook of Categorical Algebra, Vol. 1*  by Francis Borceux, that this coequalizer is an absolute colimit, i.e. that it is preserved by any functor (see **Proposition 2.10.2** ).

I was wondering:

> Can we prove coequalizers of this kind absolute without using the axiom of choice?

Intuitively, it seems to me that we do not need any choices, but I don't know enough set theory to convince myself.

Comment: What does it mean "absolute" in this context?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: A colimit is absolute if it is preserved by every functor.

Comment: Okay, there's still a lot of terminology I don't understand here, and it seems that Zhen Lin has given you an answer. So I'll give up now and maybe have someone from the category guys in my department explain this to me someday. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, the following are equivalent (in ZF):

- The axiom of choice.
- Every coequaliser in $\mathbf{Set}$ is absolute.

Indeed, one can prove (in ZF) that every surjection is the coequaliser of its kernel pair, so it suffices to prove the following assertion:

> The coequaliser diagram
>   $$R \rightrightarrows A \rightarrow A / R$$
>   is absolute if and only $A \rightarrow A / R$ splits.

You have seen that a splitting of $A \to A / R$ makes the coequaliser diagram absolute, so I'll just prove the converse. By absoluteness, the functor $\mathrm{Hom}(A / R, -)$ preserves the coequaliser, and regular epimorphisms are surjective, so there must exist a morphism $A / R \to A$ whose composite with $A \to A / R$ is $\mathrm{id}_{A / R}$, which is what I claimed.

Comment: Thank you. I feel a little dumb now.